# Symfony not loading up in EC2 instance AWS

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, virtualhost

I have a symfony website on digital ocean droplet, i am trying to migrate symfony website to aws ec2 instance. This is the tutorial i have followed : [Deploy Symfony on Ubunut 14.04](https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

I have followed each and every step according to the tutorial and have installed `composer` and other `prerequisites` needed. Here is the sites-available default config file for apache on my server :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName miscellani.co

    ServerAdmin info@miscellani.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/miscellani/web



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

But even after setting all the parameter files and everything apache is not loading up the correct index for the file but showing directories.

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35ZE3.png)

I have tried multiple tutorials but all showing the same output for symfony. If anyone can help me out here where i am doing it wrong or which file i need to install or redo any step it will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

**Update :**
Made changes as recommended by `Jan` but its still giving me the same parent directory rather than the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st add to /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 miscellani.co
127.0.0.1 www.miscellani.co
```

Run in shell

- sudo cp 000-default.conf miscellani.conf

edit **miscellani.conf**
Correct VirtualHost for Symfony is (miscellani.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName miscellani.co
    ServerAlias www.miscellani.co

    DocumentRoot  /var/www/miscellani/web

    <Directory  /var/www/miscellani/web >
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When add file run in shell command:

- sudo a2enmod rewrite
- sudo a2ensite miscellani
- sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Did all those steps but it is still showing me the parent directory.. it says site is enabled and on running the second shell command but on checking through ip it still shows the same parent directory

Comment: Is host response? 
Run in your local computer to check it (ping miscellani.co)

Comment: i am not using the domain but ip for now.. sorry.. the domain is still on reroute.. so will the servername make any problem ?
Currently using this ip http://35.161.89.46/ and it is giving me unknown host error on ping

Comment: i am not using the domain right now.. but can i configured it with the ip address without considering the domain name ? Is there anyway i can configure it based on thie ip address 35.161.89.46 ?
as domain is still attached to another hosting have not routed it yet.. will do after this is set up successfuly

Comment: The problem is with DNS now miscellani.co 's IP adres is 104.25.75.33. (on this page is running same shop :-)

If you configure virturalhost you mast use the same name then the server used your configuration

Comment: but should not the server work with the ip address and show me the site and not the directory format ? for the ip address too ? or a domain is needed to show a website even if it is hosted on an ip ?
Sorry i am new to this so want to be sure..

Comment: If i dont give any domain name in virtual host configurations will it work for the ip address ?